# Windows: Get highest numerical folder number in directory from command line

Tags: windows, command-line

Assume I have a directory as follows:

```
<whatever>\1
<whatever>\3
<whatever>\7
<whatever>\15
<whatever>\42
```

Is there a command I can run to get the highest number, e.g. 42?

Comment: Highest or latest?

Comment: Definitely the highest.

Comment: PowerShell: `gci <whatever> | ? { $_.PSisContainer } | % { [int](split-path $_.FullName -leaf) } | sort -descending | select -first 1`

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Dude my alternative is two lines of python. I wanted to know if there was some easy way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure there's a better way, but this seems to work. For positive values anyway.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

pushd whatever
set h=0
for /d %%d in (*.*) do (    
    set /a x=!h!-%%~nd  
    if "!x:~0,1!"=="-" set h=%%d    
)
popd

echo Highest value is !h!
```

First we move in the `whatever` folder.

Then we use `for /d` to loop over all subdirectories, and subtract the 'value' of the foldername (`%%~nd`, where `%%d` is the full pathname, and `~n` extracts just the name) from the current highest (`!h!`).

If the result `x` is smaller than 0 (starts with `-`) it means we found a higher value and we overwrite `!h!`.

Finally we pop back into the folder where we started.

Comment: can you translate that from clever to english

Comment: Sorry, I got a bit carried away ;-)